# Cache is empty after the Activity is returned

Tags: android, caching, random, crash, android-lifecycle

I am having this issue on an app that I made. It's a simple game that I loads data from Room database in my `onCreate` method, saves the loaded data in `List<GameData> gameData` and then starts the game.

```
gameDao.getAll()
    .subscribe(gameDatas -> {
        gameData.addAll(gameDatas);
        startGame();
    });
```

inside my `startGame`, I randomly select a number in the range `[0, gameData.size()]` and do some game related work with the corresponding `gameData`.

```
public void startGame(){
    Random random = new Random();
    int randomNumber = random.nextInt(gameData.size());

    // do something with gameData[ramdomNumber]
}
```

So, then user keeps playing and then when the user loses I send him to `GameOverActivity` with `startActivityForResult(gameOver,1123)`

Inside `GameOverActivity` user can

- restart the game
- watch an ad to continue playing
- other social related staff

So when the user presses restart button, I just finish the `GameOverActivity` which will redirect me to `onActivityResult` of `GameActivity`. Here I just call `startGame` method again, and it should supposedly start a new game.

Now the problem is sometimes for certain devices, `gameData` is getting empty and hence I am getting exception inside `startGame` when I call `random.nextInt(gameData.size())`

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 

  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity (ActivityThread.java:3790)

  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity (ActivityThread.java:3830)

  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3038)

  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11 (Unknown Source)

  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1696)

  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:105)

  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)

  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6944)

  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)

  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygote.java:327)

  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1374)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: 

  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults (ActivityThread.java:4491)

  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity (ActivityThread.java:3762)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 

  at java.util.Random.nextInt (Random.java:388)

  at com.company.game.GameActivity.startGame (GameActivity.java:149)

  at com.company.game.GameActivity.onActivityResult (GameActivity.java:477)

  at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult (Activity.java:7556)

  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults (ActivityThread.java:4487)
```

I am not understating why would `gameData` is getting cleared, and I am not able to check because I have never encountered while testing and I got the crash report from PlayConsole. Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: The line `gameData.addAll(gameData);` makes no sense. Shouldn't it be `gameData.addAll(gameDatas);` with the "s"?

Comment: yeah, its a typo

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem happens when the OS destroys the GamaActivity due to memory needs, and then recreates it for the onActivityResult. This is part of the normal Android Activity Lifecycle. Now when that happens,  `gameData` will be null, and onCreate is called to init. `onCreate` will call again the Room function to fill `gameData`, but as Room is asynchronous, it will let onCreate finish, before the `gameData` is filled. At that point, `onActivityResult` will be called, and `gameData` may still empty, as the the Room code hasn't finished, so app crashes. 
The correct way to fix this, is to move `gameData` out of the `Activity` class, and to the `Application` class. That is where it belongs, as data should be tied to the Application, not the Activity. You will have to extend the Application class, and in the onCreate of the Application, init the Room data. Just Google "Extending Android Application Class" for specific instructions. This way the data will be safe for the lifetime of the application.